# How to compare two data in the same row in Ag Grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using Angular and Ag Grid.

I have a contract_start column and and contract_end column (date type) in an Ag Grid table.
I want that the contract_end's cell's value can only be changed when the contract_end cell's date is bigger than the contract_start cell's date (in the same row).

I've searched for solutions but unfortunately I've only find information on filtering by date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your column definition for contract_end, you can specify an "editable" property, which can be either a boolean or a function that returns a boolean.

You would use the function version.
The parameter to the function is an EditableCallbackParams object, documented at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-properties/#reference-editing

In the function, you can access the row data, and compare the two column values.

For instance:

```
editable: function(params: EditableCallbackParams): boolean {
   return params.data.contract_end.getTime() > params.data.contract_start.getTime();
   
}
```

Note that I typed this from memory - I haven't tried to compile it - YMMV

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Great! Glad it worked out.
Please accept the answer. Thanks!